# React native navigation which is the best solution

Tags: react-native

Which navigation is best to use in react native with redux

1. react navigation
2. react native navigation
3. react native router flux

Is here anything best rather than this ?

Comment: It depends what you are looking for. react-navigation is the easiest to use, but react native navigation offers better performance. If you are just starting or just want a few screens and don't need anything super complex, definitely go with react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with react navigation for redux. It is pretty easy, there is a good number of tutorials as well as their documentation I would say is pretty clear: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

You should give [the Navigation router](https://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/documentation/native/hello-world.html) a try. It provides 100% native navigation on iOS and Android. It doesn’t require you to do anything special to integrate with Redux. Wrap the top level component in a Redux `Provider` component and away you go. I’ve written a [Redux example](https://github.com/grahammendick/navigation/tree/master/NavigationReactNative/sample/redux) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

React-Navigation itself answers your question [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/alternatives.html)